# parse return data from html to ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have some problem with the returned value of ajax.

this is the ajax code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var request;
    $("#flog").submit(function(event) {
        if(request)
            request.abort();
        event.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this);
        var serializedData = form.serialize();
        var btnname = $('#log').attr('name');
        var btnval = $('#log').val();
        var btn = '&'+btnname+'='+btnval;
        serializedData += btn;      

        request = $.ajax({
            type: form.attr('method'),
            url: form.attr('action'),
            data: serializedData,
        });

        request.done(function(data, status, jdXHR) {
            alert(data);
        });

        request.fail(function(jdXHR, status, error) {

        });
    });
});
```

it takes data from a form and send it to another page.

this is the second page:

```
<?php include 'head.php'; ?>
    <?php
    if($_POST['login']) {

    session_regenerate_id(true);
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "Alessandro", "ciao", "freetime")
        or die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));

    $query = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE username="' . $_POST['user'] . '"';
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
        mysqli_close($con);
        session_unset();
        session_destroy();
        $res = false;
        return $res;
    }

    $query = 'SELECT password FROM users WHERE username="' . $_POST['user'] . '"';
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    $line = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
    if(md5($_POST['password']) != $line['password']) {
        mysqli_close($con);
        session_unset();
        session_destroy();
        return false;
    }
?>
<?php include 'foot.php'; ?>
```

and in .done the returned data is all the html page.
How can I retrieve only a data, like $res? I tried with json_encode() but with no results.
If in the second page I delete the lines include 'head.php' and include 'foot.php' it works. But I need that the secon page is html, too.
Somenone can help me?

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). And since you're doing an ajax call, you can't "return" from php->js. You have to produce OUTPUT in php which can get sent back to the JS code. e.g. `echo 'failed'` or something.

Comment: even if I use echo $res in the returned data there is all the html page

Answer (score 0):

Dont use the Data attribute from AJAX.

Replace

```
request.done(function(data, status, jdXHR) {
        alert(data);
    });
```

with

```
request.done(function(data, status, jdXHR) {
        alert(jdXHR.responseText);
    });
```

Comment: is the same. I have all the html text, while I want only the variable $res

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in a much simpler way.
In PHP store the result of the attempted login into a variable, for instance $result =0; to start with
If the login is valid change it to 1 and return it to ajax by doing an echo at the end of your PHP file. If you need other value returned such as the name you could add it to the variable with a separator such as || for instance.

in javascript collect your return and go data = data.split('||');
if (data[0] == 0){alert("Welcome back " + data[1]);}else{alert("wrong login...")}

Previous use is correct, you need to escape the user collected in your PHP script.
Hope this helps.

Comment: In this way in data there is only the variable $result?

Comment: yes, you can store anything you want in it and then separate the pieces you want. I find this ideal for relatively small amount of data return as it is the case for you here.

Comment: Thank you! :) but how can I retrieve only the variable $result, without return all the html page

Comment: don't have HTML tags in the PHP page so the only thing on your page is the value of your variable. HTML tags are for the browser but there is no browser going onto your PHP file.

Comment: thank you. I wanted to have an html page in order to display it if javascript is disabled